# MATLAB Code - Color Image Histogram

Tags: image-processing, histogram, matlab

I want to create a color bar histogram of an image which has been subjected to adaptive color quantization with each channel quantized into q=16 bins i.e. in all q*q*q = q3 = 16 * 16 *16 = 4096 bins.
I want the histogram bars representing bins to show the mean color of pixels present in the respective bins and the histogram bars arranged in descending order of number of pixels. Can this histogram be generated through MATLAB functions & syntax?
I will greatly appreciate Peer help / assistance in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is within imhist()'s capability, I think.